# What exactly are Binaries in Artifactory

Tags: storage, artifactory, binaries

[image: Artifactory Storage Snippet]

In Artifactory, under the Storage in Monitoring tab, the Binaries size is 1.57 GB, whereas the Artifacts size is just 6.27 MB. What exactly are Binaries in Artifactory, as they are taking a lot of Storage.

Is it possible to delete these Binaries without affecting the Artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binaries size = sum of the sizes all the binaries you uploaded

Artifacts size = sum of the size of all the artifacts stored

Optimization is the amount of optimization provided due to checksum based storage which is in your case 25617%

It appears you are uploading the same binary multiple times to different folders and hence the above situation.

Comment: Only thing to correct here is that the optimization will be under 100%, meaning that artifactory is saving you storage